# nodejs and javascript communication

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a chat-system in javascript with nodejs as server-side language. So far I've used Socket.io as I though it would be able to handle a large number of clients (aiming at 100k+) but today, 1 week before we are releasing beta I learned that Socket.io have major problems with scalability and so I've decided to change my approach. I need quick, live data transfers between server and client and now I don't know where to look. Maybe simply WebSockets and try to develope these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely use ws, it is the fastest library atm.

https://github.com/einaros/ws

We are already using it in our project, weezeel, and it is insanely fast plus it supports thousands of concurrent connections.

Comment: I'm sorry, done so much research today my brain has no more capacity. I'll try it out thanks!